# Can i use PHP SQL server extension to connect to a MySQL db?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to test some SQL server functions like sqlsrv_connect, i installed sqlsrv driver succesfully, is it possible to use the sqlsrv_connect function to connect to a MySQL database or do i have to install a MS SQL Server ?

Thank you

Comment: This will never work if you want to test MS SQL server stuff, since ... MySQL isn't MS SQL ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlsrv.php):

> The SQLSRV extension allows you to access Microsoft SQL Server and SQL Azure databases when running PHP on Windows.

So, you have to install a MS SQL Server. Because that's what the extension is for.

Answer (score 0):

[`sqlsrv_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) only connects to a MS SQL Server. You need to use either `PDO` or `mysqli` to connect to MySql from PHP